# How to access controls within a jquery ui dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

[File uploads not working within jQuery UI Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756480/file-uploads-not-working-within-jquery-ui-dialog)

From the post above,

"Dialog moves its content outside of its form, and appends it to body. Probably to gain better control of the DOM, to make sure it always displays in the center, above everything else, and is not contained in some absolutely positioned DIV or so..."

If that is so, how can I go about having dynamic content on the popup dialog?

Lets say, I want to load a directoty tree on the dialog popup.

I am using ASP.Net MVC 3.0.

When I click on a button on page1, I make an ajax call to a controller (controller1). There is a view (view1) associated with the controller. I get the result and set that as the dialog body and open the dialog.

Now in view1, I have added a javascript element for setting a div's content dynamically.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

       $("#treeViewDivOnPopup")
.html('<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>');

});
</script>
```

I have this div - treeViewDivOnPopup on view1. All the static text on the view is correctly displayed on the dialog when I execute this. But the script is not able to find the div dynamically.

How can I get this to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do this from the parent page. I could manipulate the div on the popup from the open funciton, in the jquery ui dialog call.